# Is it possible to pass in variables for Terraform target modules via command line?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to run the following commands. Essentially passing an environment variable when targeting a module.

```
terraform plan -target module.network -var 'env=dev'

terraform apply -target module.network -var 'env=dev'
```

However it complains the variable is not declared in the root module even though it is declared in the module folder itself.
I then tried different combinations of declaring variables with no luck.

1. Declaring the variable within /main.tf
2. Setting the variables within /terraform.tfvars

Here is my file and folder structure.

/main.tf

```
# Network (VPC, Gateway, Subnets, Security Groups)
module "network" {
    source = "./modules/network"
}
```

/modules/network/vars.tf

```
variable "env" {
    default = "dev"
}

variable "region" {
    default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "subnet_cidr" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24","10.0.3.0/24"]
}

# Retrieve AZs Dynamically
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}
```

/modules/network/main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    profile    = "default"
    region     = var.aws_region
    version    = "2.26"
}

# Create VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block            = "10.0.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames  = true
    enable_dns_support    = true
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.env}-vpc"
    }
}

# Create Subnets Dynamically from list
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
    count       = "${length(var.subnet_cidr)}"
    vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    cidr_block  = "${element(var.subnet_cidr,count.index)}"
    availability_zone = "${element(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names,count.index)}"
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.env}-subnet-${count.index+1}"
    }
}

# Create internet gateway to give our VPC access to the outside world
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    tags = {
        Name = "${var.env}-gateway"
    }
}

# Grant the VPC internet access on its main route table
resource "aws_route" "internet_access" {
    route_table_id         = "${aws_vpc.vpc.main_route_table_id}"
    destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id             = "${aws_internet_gateway.default.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I was able to pass in the variables to the network module.

Previously, I was treating the root module and network module as the same scope. Variables from the root need to be passed into the module.

```
variable "env" {
    default = "dev"
}

variable "aws_region" {
    default = "us-east-1"
}

# Network (VPC, Gateway, Subnets)
module "network" {
    source = "./modules/network"
    aws_region = var.aws_region
    env = var.env
}
```

---

Then run this command.

```
terraform plan -target module.network -var 'env=dev'
```

Comment: Please note that you should not use `-target` except in exceptional circumstances. For more information, see [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting).

Comment: Yes. The exceptional circumstance I am facing is the PostgreSQL provider doesn't have the ability to wait for an AWS Database to be provisioned prior to creating databases and database users. The depends_on attribute is not possible with that provider. See: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2430